# Include number of observations in textreg ARIMA output

Tags: r, texreg

I'm running several time series regressions. My example is using different data, and I have taken NO care in making these models correct - they are just illustrative for my question. Sorry, I used a downloaded dataset rather than a created one. I hope that's okay.

My task is printing texreg outputs for various models, including but not limited to ARIMA forecasts. I need to include the number of observations for all models. The texreg extract functions do not include the number of observations for ARIMA objects - or at least the number of observations will never print in the gof statistics.

Two options I've thought of, and I'm hoping for help implementing either or both of them:

1. Add a custom row to the gof statistics with the number of observations included. This *should* be possible using custom.gof.rows, as discussed [here](https://github.com/leifeld/texreg/issues/128) and [here](https://github.com/leifeld/texreg/commit/29c7189d8492c0d940f7f25044ba557d247d93fc). However, custom.gof.rows does not appear to a part of the texreg package as of version 1.36.23. Perhaps it was taken out for some reason? Not sure.

If there is a secret version of texreg that includes custom.gof.rows, can anyone link to it?

> ```
> library('ggplot2')
> library('forecast')
> library('tseries')
> library('texreg')
> library('lmtest')
>
> #data can be downloaded from: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bike+Sharing+Dataset
>
> #Change to data path
> path<-c("")
>
> #Import data
> daily_data = read.csv(paste(path,'day.csv',sep=""), header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
>
> #Mark a shift date
> daily_data$shift<- ifelse(daily_data$instant>12,1,0)
>
> #Create time series data
> dt <- ts(daily_data$temp, frequency=12, start= c(2011, 1))
>
> #Define input vars for ARIMA
> (xvars <- as.matrix(daily_data[, c("instant", "shift")]))
>
> #Basic ARIMA
> a<- arima(dt, xreg=xvars)
>
> #Auto-ARIMA
> b<- auto.arima(dt, xreg=xvars)
>
> ##Where I want to include number of observations either automatically or using custom.gof.rows
> screenreg(list(coeftest(b),a))
> ```

[This is the output, which I had to link (sorry)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q63IA.jpg)

Note that the model objects themselves aren't the reason (I think). I can extract the number of observations myself and print them separately.

> ```
> #Both models have number of observations in their objects that I can extract
> nobs_a<-nobs(a)
> nobs_b<-nobs(b)
>
> cat("Number of obs ARIMA: ",nobs_a,"\n")
>
> cat("Number of obs Auto-ARIMA: ",nobs_b,"\n")
>
> ##Custom.gof.rows doesn't appear to be in texreg version 1.36.23
> screenreg((list(coeftest(b),a)), custom.gof.rows = list(nobs_a,nobs_b))
> ```

2. Modify the extract function to include the number of observations so that they will automatically be included, as discussed the extended documentation [here](http://www2.uaem.mx/r-mirror/web/packages/texreg/vignettes/texreg.pdf). This I'm completely new to, but I've made an attempt below to modify the textreg extract.Arima function to retrieve the number of observations using nobs.

> ```
> function (model, include.pvalues = FALSE, include.aic = TRUE, 
>           include.loglik = TRUE, ...)  {   mask <- model$mask   nam <- names(model$coef)   
>    co <- model$coef   sdev <-
>     sqrt(diag(model$var.coef))   if (include.pvalues == TRUE) {
>     t.rat <- rep(NA, length(mask))
>     t.rat[mask] <- co[mask]/sdev
>     pt <- 2 * pnorm(-abs(t.rat))
>     setmp <- rep(NA, length(mask))
>     setmp[mask] <- sdev   }   else {
>     pt <- numeric()
>     setmp <- sdev   }   gof <- numeric()   gof.names <- character()   gof.decimal <- logical()   if 
>      (include.aic == TRUE) {
>     aic <- AIC(model)
>     gof <- c(gof, aic)
>     gof.names <- c(gof.names, "AIC")
>     gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, TRUE)   }   
>
>     ##This is the section I added - ripped more or less intact from the extract.lm function         
>     if (include.nobs == TRUE) {
>     gof <- c(gof, nobs)
>     gof.names <- c(gof.names, "Num. obs.")
>     gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, FALSE)   }   
>
>     if (include.loglik == TRUE) {
>     lik <- model$loglik
>     gof <- c(gof, lik)
>     gof.names <- c(gof.names, "Log Likelihood")
>     gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, TRUE)   }   
>     tr <- createTexreg(coef.names = nam, coef = co, se = setmp, 
>                      pvalues = pt, gof.names = gof.names, gof = gof, gof.decimal = gof.decimal)   > 
>       return(tr) } <bytecode:
> ```

This runs but breaks the textreg function. If I'm on the wrong track, I'd also be happy to be linked to a tutorial for changing the extract functions generally. You may also notice that I'm using coeftest() in the code above to extract the Auto-ARIMA coefficients. I'm tangentially interested in writing an exract function for Auto-ARIMA forecast objects. I think this would be necessary anyway, because nobs only works on b itself, and not on coeftest(b). That's an aside though - I can figure that out when I get there.

Can anyone help with either or both avenues, or perhaps propose a different method for including the number of observations in a texreg output?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `custom.gof.rows` argument was added to the `texreg`, `screenreg` etc. functions about a year ago and has not found its way to CRAN yet, but will eventually. For the time being, you can install the most recent version from GitHub if you'd like to use this argument. You can do so as follows (and will need to have installed the `remotes` package first):

```r
library(remotes)
install_github("leifeld/texreg")
```

The `custom.gof.rows` argument takes a named list of vectors. You were simply providing two values for the number of observations as separate arguments to the `custom.gof.rows` argument. Instead, you need to wrap both in a vector and attach a name to it, for example "Num. obs.". You can do this as follows:

```r
screenreg(list(coeftest(b), a),
          custom.gof.rows = list("Num. obs." = c(nobs(b), nobs(a))))
```

That said, I have now added the number of observations to the `extract` methods for ARIMA models anyway, so you won't need this argument anymore.

Your attempt to modify the `extract` method on your own almost worked. You would have needed to include the `include.nobs = TRUE` argument also in the function head, and you would have needed to register the function as a method for the generic `extract` function as described in the [article in the Journal of Statistical Software](http://dx.doi.org/10.18637/jss.v055.i08).

To make your life easier, I have done this for you. So if you install the most recent version of `texreg` from GitHub as per the instructions above, it should automatically include the number of observations.

The `arima` function you are using is defined in the `stats` package. It returns an `Arima` object. I have updated its `extract` method accordingly. The `auto.arima` function you are using above is a wrapper for that same function and returns an object with class `forecast_ARIMA` (and formerly, and secondarily, `ARIMA`). This is a bit confusing, but it's important to be aware of these distinctions. I have updated both methods for you with the number of observations, so your code

```r
screenreg(list(coeftest(b), a))
```

should now return the following output:

```
======================================
                Model 1    Model 2    
--------------------------------------
ar1              0.96 ***             
                (0.04)                
ar2             -0.30 ***             
                (0.05)                
ar3              0.13 *               
                (0.05)                
ar4              0.02                 
                (0.05)                
ar5              0.17 ***             
                (0.04)                
intercept        0.43 **      0.21 ***
                (0.13)       (0.05)   
instant          0.00         0.00 *  
                (0.00)       (0.00)   
shift            0.02         0.25 ***
                (0.05)       (0.05)   
--------------------------------------
AIC                        -440.26    
BIC                        -421.88    
Log Likelihood              224.13    
Num. obs.                   731       
======================================
*** p < 0.001; ** p < 0.01; * p < 0.05
```

Note, however, that you are using the `coeftest` function from the `lmtest` package for model `b`, which has a separate class and hence `extract` method and does not return the number of observations. To get the number of observations also for Model `b`, you could include it directly, without `coeftest`:

```
screenreg(list(b, a), single.row = TRUE)
```

This returns the following output:

```
=======================================================
                Model 1              Model 2           
-------------------------------------------------------
ar1                 0.96 (0.04) ***                    
ar2                -0.30 (0.05) ***                    
ar3                 0.13 (0.05) *                      
ar4                 0.02 (0.05)                        
ar5                 0.17 (0.04) ***                    
intercept           0.43 (0.13) **      0.21 (0.05) ***
instant             0.00 (0.00)         0.00 (0.00) *  
shift               0.02 (0.05)         0.25 (0.05) ***
-------------------------------------------------------
AIC             -2183.71             -440.26           
AICc            -2183.46                               
BIC             -2142.36             -421.88           
Log Likelihood   1100.86              224.13           
Num. obs.         731                 731              
=======================================================
*** p < 0.001; ** p < 0.01; * p < 0.05
```

If you do insist on using `coeftest`, you can save the output of the `extract` function in an intermediate object and manipulate this object. In the following code, I take the GOF block from the version without `coeftest` and inject it into the version with `coeftest` and then hand over the manipulated object instead of the original one to the `screenreg` function:

```
tr_b_coeftest <- extract(coeftest(b))
tr_b_plain <- extract(b)
tr_b_coeftest@gof.names <- tr_b_plain@gof.names
tr_b_coeftest@gof <- tr_b_plain@gof
tr_b_coeftest@gof.decimal <- tr_b_plain@gof.decimal
screenreg(list(tr_b_coeftest, a), single.row = TRUE)
```

This returns the following output:

```
=======================================================
                Model 1              Model 2           
-------------------------------------------------------
ar1                 0.96 (0.04) ***                    
ar2                -0.30 (0.05) ***                    
ar3                 0.13 (0.05) *                      
ar4                 0.02 (0.05)                        
ar5                 0.17 (0.04) ***                    
intercept           0.43 (0.13) **      0.21 (0.05) ***
instant             0.00 (0.00)         0.00 (0.00) *  
shift               0.02 (0.05)         0.25 (0.05) ***
-------------------------------------------------------
AIC             -2183.71             -440.26           
AICc            -2183.46                               
BIC             -2142.36             -421.88           
Log Likelihood   1100.86              224.13           
Num. obs.         731                 731              
=======================================================
*** p < 0.001; ** p < 0.01; * p < 0.05
```