# Using texreg to print mean of dependent variable instead of R squared in R

Tags: r, latex, regression, texreg

I have some regression models that I want to export to LaTeX. I am using the package "texreg". The final output is:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l c c}
\hline
 & Model 1 & Model 2 \\
\hline
as.factor(treat)1               & $145227140331.44$    &                      \\
                               & $(2648642987059.38)$ &                      \\
as.factor(msj)1                &                      & $-647801609586.01$   \\
                               &                      & $(3435830264390.74)$ \\
as.factor(msj)2                &                      & $433277589458.84$    \\
                               &                      & $(3288915232361.39)$ \\
as.factor(msj)3                &                      & $-1691975577225.66$  \\
                               &                      & $(3293603457594.94)$ \\
as.factor(msj)4                &                      & $-843647941334.40$   \\
                               &                      & $(3359975197112.69)$ \\
as.factor(msj)5                &                      & $576301517588.01$    \\
                               &                      & $(3349253720672.64)$ \\
as.factor(msj)6                &                      & $3301581741709.62$   \\
                               &                      & $(3403672471154.21)$ \\
as.factor(msj)7                &                      & $17431285033.90$     \\
                               &                      & $(3695545300670.01)$ \\
\hline
Num. obs.                      & $1000$               & $1000$               \\
R$^2$ (full model)             & $0.02$               & $0.03$               \\
R$^2$ (proj model)             & $0.00$               & $0.00$               \\
Adj. R$^2$ (full model)        & $0.01$               & $0.01$               \\
Adj. R$^2$ (proj model)        & $-0.01$              & $-0.01$              \\
Num. groups: as.factor(strata) & $10$                 & $10$                 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\scriptsize{$^{***}p<0.001$; $^{**}p<0.01$; $^{*}p<0.05$}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Statistical models}
\label{table:coefficients}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Instead of the latex output displaying the R-squared and Adjusted R-squared, can I get it to show the mean of the dependent variable?

Comment: off-topic: instead of the `center` environment, better use `\centering` to avoid the additional vertical space.

Comment: You should show a minimal reproducible code example. That will make it easier to help you. Have you tried using arguments `include.rsquared = FALSE`, `include.adjrs = FALSE`, and `custom.gof.rows = list("Mean of DV" = c(a, b))`, where `a` and `b` are the means you'd like to show? See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61527052/.